# Why does Swift allocates four words of storage in heap for a class?

Tags: swift, memory, reference, heap-memory, allocation

I was studying heap and stack allocation in Swift and found out that most of the sources on the internet referred to the *Understanding Swift Performance* WWDC 2016 Session 416.

The video **compares stack and heap allocation** with the images at the bottom.
Struct is allocated in the **stack with only two words of storage**, each containing the struct's properties. However, **class has four words of storage**:

- a reference in the stack
- a blue box in the heap
- two storage areas in the heap each containing the class' properties

What I've understood is that there is a **reference** holding the heap memory location in the stack. However, I couldn't figure out what those **blue boxes** are. Does that hold an **instance of the class**? What exactly is in the blue storage area?

**Struct allocation in the stack**
[image]

**Class allocation in the heap**
[image]

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: In the second case, the entire "Heap" box is the `Point` instance, where `point1` and `point2` refer to the same instance. The blue areas are just internal metadata belonging to the instance (namely, a class pointer and a reference count). See [Memory layout in Swift](https://theswiftdev.com/memory-layout-in-swift/) for more details.